# Drive relay with Npn transistor thanks to RTC and Rpi

Tags: relay, raspberry-pi, rtc

It's my first project in electrical engineering and I am not very sure about what I'm doing.

I would like to drive a relay thanks to a Rpi and a RTC clock that has a alarm feature (ds3231 with high-z/active low) ... relay that will itself drive the raspberry pi.
To sum up:

1. The RTC send a signal that turn on the Relay and thus the RPI
2. The RPi reset the RTC alarm to it previous state and configure it to
   trigger again in a determined time
3. The Rpi do what it has to do
4. The Rpi shut down and everything is back to normal
   I have to keep in mind to keep the current consumption as low as possible during the "sleep" phases

So far: I intended to use NPN transistor like on my scheme.
in

1. Both the Rpi and Ds3231 are High-z so the 5 V pull up and there is 5 V both in the base and emitter of the NPN => It doesn't let the current go.
   2)The DS2132 become on open drain .. the NPN lets the current go
2. the Rpi turn on and also become on open drain

[image]

My main preoccupation is: would this circuit work (and if not why?). I have of course to add a diode on the relay

Ps: A GPIO pin is in an high impedance state when no current is applied to Rpi, isn't it?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to turn the relay on if either an RTC brings an open drain output low or the Raspberry Pi provides a certain logic state, the below circuit would do this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNl7y4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The Rpi GPIO should be brought high to keep the relay in, and it should be push-pull, not open drain.

The Rpi outputs are not guaranteed 5V tolerant so they cannot be pulled up to 5V reliably. You need a catch diode across the relay, as shown. Further, it is unlikely that either the RTC or the Raspberry Pi will be very happy directly driving a relay- in your circuit about all the relay current goes through the Raspberry Pi or RTC.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It all more clear in my head now. 
I just have an hard time to visualise what happen when the Rpi gpio is high and the Rtc is high impedance ?

Comment: Then the relay is powered. The logic is that the relay is powered if the open-drain output is low *or* the GPIO is high.

Comment: This diagram works like a charm ! Just tested it with a mosfet  instead of the relay ( without the diode) and still seem fine for the moment. (Gate to the PNP, Source to ground and Drain to the device to control and 5v)

Comment: Your solution would work as well, if the Rpi/R2 and the DS3231 can each sink enough current to drive the relay coil.  Spehro's approach will work with a lower drive requirement.  Also, D1 isn't addressed, but it's vital for preventing damage to your drive transistor from the field collapsing in the relay coil.